# Whats the best way to get the current audio playback level?

Tags: audio, raspbian, alsa

I'm playing an audio stream with ffplay. Is there a simple way to get the current level of the audio that is playing? Not what the volume is set to but the actual audio levels being played?

I need the data to be readable by a web app on the device.

Also, I'm not using pulseaudio.

Answer (score 1):

for ALSA and raspberry pi - https://github.com/pimoroni/pivumeter

based on this - http://laugeo.free.fr/ameter.html